# NGINX / Wordpress Site - Increasing php.ini max_execution_time = 600 doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I'm testing my PHP Limit on WordPress site and keep getting a 504 Gateway Time-out.

I'm changing the max_execution_time in php.ini to reflect the value of 600.

Followed by restart when I test the PHP Limit it gives me a 504 Gateway Time-out.

Upon checking php -i I get the following result; max_execution_time => 0 => 0

the ini file is pointing at /etc/php/7.0/cli and this is the one I am configuring.

Contacting support they have stated;

> That command checks the overall php ini settings, not for the
>   application. The bad gateway error may be because of an error in the
>   configuration setup. Try verifying the configuration file and checking
>   your error logs.

Checking contents for error log, nothing recorded.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 3 sets of timeouts when dealing with simple NGINX + PHP-FPM stack.

One is PHP engine, which you have already adjusted to unlimited.

Second is PHP-FPM, which is controlled via `request_terminate_timeout` in your pool settings. The default is usually like this:

```
;request_terminate_timeout = 0
```

Value of `0` would mean that there is no limit set by PHP-FPM itself, so you likely won't have to adjust that.

Finally, there are NGINX timeouts for FastCGI communication, which are controlled through a couple of directives in your NGINX config. You mostly care about `fastcgi_read_timeout`:

> If the FastCGI server does not transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.

You would place it in your PHP handler location, e.g.:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
```

P.S. Don't confuse "Bad Gateway" (502) and "Gateway Time-out" (504) errors. Those are different errors: the former is for a failure to communicate with PHP-FPM (typically a sign of severe misconfiguration, defunct / not running PHP-FPM process), while the latter is exceeding timeout *while communicating* with PHP-FPM.